# JAVA- JFrame- non static method cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, swing, methods, static, jframe

This issue appears to be very common but I couldn't find any solution for my problem. 
Well, maybe if I wasn't so n00bish at programming, I'd understand everything and would solve the problem.

Anyway, here's the code:

```
package kalk;

import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author BADASS BOSS
 */
public class Kalkulator extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Kalkulator
     */
    private double liczba1, liczba2;
    private double wynik=0;
    private int nrdzialania=0;
    private boolean dopierwszej=true;
    private Toolkit glownytoolkit;
    //dzialania
    //1-dodawanie
    //2-odejmowanie
    //3-mnozenie
    //4-dzielenie
    private double pobierzliczbe(String s)
    {
        double temp;        
        temp = 0;
        try
        {
            temp = Double.valueOf(s);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "FATAL ERROR!!" + e,"Coś się zepsuło!!!!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        return temp;
    }
    private void robdzialanie()
    {
        String bufor;
        liczba1 = pobierzliczbe(jTextField1.getText());
        liczba2 = pobierzliczbe(jTextField3.getText());
        bufor = "";
        if (nrdzialania==1) wynik = liczba1 + liczba2;
        else if (nrdzialania==2) wynik = liczba1 - liczba2;
        else if (nrdzialania==3) wynik = liczba1 * liczba2;
        else if (nrdzialania==4)
        {
            if (liczba2==0) bufor="FATAL ERROR!! Nie można dzielić przez zero!!!";
            else wynik = liczba1 / liczba2;
        }
        if (nrdzialania!=0) bufor = String.valueOf(wynik);
        else bufor = "FATAL ERROR!! Argument jest pusty albo niepoprawny!!";
        jTextField4.setText(bufor); 
    }
    public Kalkulator() {
        initComponents();
        glownytoolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    }
    private void dajnasrodek()
    {
        int x;
        int y;
        int szerokość_ekranu;
        int wysokość_ekranu;
        int wysokość_ramki;
        int szerokość_ramki;
        szerokość_ekranu = glownytoolkit.getScreenSize().width;
        wysokość_ekranu = glownytoolkit.getScreenSize().height;
        szerokość_ramki = this.getSize().width;
        wysokość_ramki = this.getSize().height;
        x = (szerokość_ekranu - szerokość_ramki)/2;
        y = (wysokość_ekranu - wysokość_ramki)/2;
        this.setLocation(x, y);
    }
    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {


////some unnecessary stuff I guess



    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Kalkulator.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Kalkulator.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Kalkulator.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Kalkulator.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        //Kalkulator gc = new Kalkulator();
        //gc.dajnasrodek();
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
            }
          }

        );
        //Kalkulator gc = new Kalkulator();
        //gc.dajnasrodek();
        //ActionEvent klik;
        //jButton18ActionPerformed();    
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton10;
   ///some unnecessary stuff                 
}
```

Sorry about the Polish language but I hope the names of the variables aren't that important to understand anyway.

Alright, so here's the deal: when I try to reference `dajnasrodek();` from the main method, I get the error as shown in the title- `non static method cannot be referenced from a static context`. I tried to change the `dajnasrodek()` method to static but that didn't help so well since some other errors appear instead.

Any clever ideas?? Any kind of help will be very appreciated!! Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: So which line is the error on?  I would try to compile it myself, but I'm not set up for whichever character set you're using, and I'm not going to mess around with my settings just to answer this question.  (It's probably going to get closed before I can type my answer anyway)

Comment: That's what I expected. Well, I want to reference the dajnasrodek() method from the main method but I don't even know exactly where to put it... Do you at least know what I mean?? I can seem very unclear in that since I'm a beginner at programming.

Comment: Or, to put it simple- the method dajnasrodek() means exactly "center the screen" and all I want to do is to make the program automatically center the screen after the startup. Any ideas how to do this?? dajnasrodek() method is the algorithm I want to run but no luck so far

Comment: No, it seems that you are describing a compile error.  But all I see is code that SHOULD compile.  If you want help resolving a compile error, you'll need to show us the code that HAS the error, not some other piece of code that DOESN'T have the error.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put your code in the main method.  Instead I'd put it into the class constructor for the class the holds the main method, in your case Kalkulator.  Then instantiate Kalkulator in the main method.  Kalkulator won't be static, so you won't recieve this message.  If you want to know why you're getting this error, its because the main method is declared as static, and as the error suggests a static thing can't access something not static. Check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) out.